# Public share using samba

Tags: samba

I'm trying to make a simple read only public share using samba.  What am I doing wrong?  The rest of the samba.config is stock.

```
[Share]
  path = /home/root/share
  public = yes
  writable = no
  printable = no
  browseable = yes
  guest ok = yes
  readable = yes
```

Comment: What is the actual problem / errors you see? What do logs show?

Comment: The "actual problem" is that I cannot browse this folder from my windows computer or map to it.  I can see the server under network and when I click on it I see the folder but when I click on the folder I can't get access to the contents.  Windows gives says it cannot access the share.  I'll check logs and post anything relevant in a few

Comment: The logfiles are empty.  I removed the writable and readable parameters and replaced them with read only = yes

Comment: If the log files are empty, that suggests that smbd/nmbd are not running.

Comment: Yes it is running but this is part the output from /etc/init.d/samba status:

'Active: active (running) since Wed 2016-07-27 21:42:04 BST; 1h 11min ago'


'Jul 27 21:53:40 minibian smbd[837]: pam_unix(samba:session): session closed for user nobody'

Comment: You probably checked this already, but just in case: Besides the permissions in Samba, the native permissions of the files and directories have to allow "everyone" access as well. If I recall correctly (which I might not) the "execute" permission for "everyone" needs to set on directories in order to allow them to be browsed.

Answer (score 1):

Your posted configuration looks ok, other than the `readable = yes` line. `testparm` shows that to be an unknown parameter on my system. This simplified version works for me:

`[test]
   path = /home/user/share
   read only = yes
   guest ok = yes`

Just a reminder, if you make changes to your *smb.conf* file be sure to restart *smbd*.

If the directory is visible in Windows but not accessible then that sounds like a permission issue. Make sure the directory has the correct permissions. You should have read and execute permissions set for all users. To accomplish this you can do `chmod a+rx /home/<user>/share` (replace `<user>` with a valid user home directory).

I think the real issue is the location of `share`. If ***/home/root*** is *root's* home directory (mine is at ***/root***, not ***/home/root***) it should be set to have read, write and execute permission only for *root*. If this is the case I would recommend not putting the share in that directory. One appropriate place for a public read only share would be in ***/srv***. This is from [FHS](http://www.pathname.com/fhs/pub/fhs-2.3.html#SRVDATAFORSERVICESPROVIDEDBYSYSTEM):

> /srv : Data for services provided by this system
>
> **Rationale**
>
> This main purpose of specifying this is so that users may find the location of the data files for particular service, and so that services which require a single tree for readonly data, writable data and scripts (such as cgi scripts) can be reasonably placed. Data that is only of interest to a specific user should go in that users' home directory.